# Meshlab: How do I extract x,y,z coordinates of points?

Tags: meshlab

I'm new to meshlab, so my question is probably very basic:

I have a ply file of a 3D image. I want to get the xyz-coordinates of certain points of this image. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming. Please delete it and ask it on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 7):

In the latest (beta) version of MeshLab you can use the info (yellow (i) on the toolbar) or the measure tool (tape icon) to get info. If you press `P` you can have all the needed info (coords of the picked point, id of the face, its vertices etc)